# How to convert C# function to python with pythonnet

Tags: python.net

I have question that is related to a [different problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77243643/running-into-a-pythonnet-error-on-a-net-assembly-with-comvisiblefalse), there I'm having trouble with the `InteropServices` class.
Somehow I cannot get the right input variable type in Python.

While searching in the old codebase (Python2.7 and IronPython era) I found this `C#` helper class:

```
    public VariantWrapper GetListWrapper(List<string> input)
        {
            var list = new object[input.Count()];
            for (int i = 0; i < input.Count(); i++)
            {
                list[i] = (object)input[i];
            }
            return new System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper(list);
        }
```

With this, I now know what the final result needs to be, a `Python` list that will be converted to this InteroptServices VariantWrapper, which is an unmanaged object according to the [.NET help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.variantwrapper.-ctor?view=net-7.0)

My previous working code in `Python` looked like this:

```
    questionList = [question]  # question is python string
    QvStringList = System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper(questionList)
```

Which sadly keeps throwing errors now.

Can this `C#` helper class be converted to a `Python` method?

BR.
LVX

## Edit 1

Apparently this `VariantWrapper` 'is' the problem. After digging through the SDK's DLL Interopt class types. I have found five different types that are used:

- `System.Boolean&`
- `System.Int32&`
- `System.Double&`
- `System.String&`
- `System.Object&`

For four of them the default python types can be used directly while addressing them via the pythonnet clr references. Just one of them is hard to get working:

- `System.Boolean&` can be addressed via Python's `True` or `False`
- `System.Int32&` can be addressed via Python's `int` type, for example passing a 0
- `System.Double&` can be addressed via Python's `float` type, for example passing a 0.0
- `System.String&` can be addressed via Python's `str` type, for example an empty string: ""
- `System.Object&` cannot be addressed any more (atleast in .NET Framework 4.8) with the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper()` like for example wrapping in List into an `Object` System.Runtime.InteropServices.VariantWrapper([])

Does anyone have a good idea or method to get this Object& working in pythonnet?